# File download not working

Tags: magento2, file, download

```
<?php

namespace Modulename\Merchant\Controller\Adminhtml\Document;

class Filedownload extends \Modulename\Merchant\Controller\Adminhtml\Document
{
protected $_downloader;

private $logger;

protected $_directory;

protected $_documentFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Adolmedia\Merchant\Model\DocumentFactory $documentFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->_downloader = $fileFactory;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_documentFactory = $documentFactory;
    $this->_directory = $directory;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry);
}

public function execute()
{
    $documentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('document_id');

//        try {
        $document = $this->_documentFactory->create()->load($documentId);

        $filePath = $document->getFilePath();

        $fileName = $document->getFileName();

        $file = $this->_directory->getPath("media") . $filePath . $fileName; // do your validations /** * do file download */
        return $this->_downloader->create($fileName, @file_get_contents($file));
 //        }
 //        catch (\Exception $e) {
//            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
//        }
}
}
```

when I click download link it shows in browser.

The web page at http://127.0.0.1/magento23/admin/merchant/document/filedownload/document_id/2/key/8800ab485374f4bb24103af1e0472723f66314f9f2914d220fe3ba69738ad509/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

How can I solve this issue??

Comment: Have you created Document.php at \Modulename\Merchant\Controller\Adminhtml path ? if not then first you should extend your class with \Magento\Backend\App\Action

Apart from this in constructor, parent constructor should be called with only context .... Put a die inside execute method and check if it works or not.

Comment: yes i have already  created parent class.. tested using echo statement .. only this return $this->_downloader->create($fileName, @file_get_contents($file)); causing error

Comment: Have suggested an answer. Try that and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below.

```
$content_type = 'application/zip';
$this->_downloader->create(
    $fileName,
    [
        'type' => 'filename',
        'value' => $filePath . $fileName,
        'rm' => false
    ],
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::ROOT,
    $content_type
);
```

Give appropriate content_type for desired filetype and in below line
'value' => $filePath . $fileName

Make sure the $filepath is absolute filepath like /var/www/html/magento/pub/media

This should work.

Comment: Prefect answer... thank u so much ...  yash7690

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote and accept answer so that it help others as well.

Comment: $file = $this->_directory->getPath("media") . $filePath . $fileName; // do your validations /** * do file download */

            $content_type = 'application/pdf';
            return $this->_downloader->create(
            $fileName,
            [
                'type' => 'filename',
                'value' => $file,
                'rm' => false
            ],
            \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::ROOT,
            $content_type
            );    need to call \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory to get directory path

Comment: Ok thats perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass two more parameters in factory  intialization:

```
$this->_downloader->create(
$fileName, 
@file_get_contents($file),
'base dir of the file to download here',
'application/octet-stream'//content type
);
```